# aws autoscaling group ec2 instance create before destroy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

In the terraform there is a create_before_destroy setting so it means during the refresh the old vm is still running, the new one is started and after that the old one is destroyed. Is there a possibility to set this setting via aws cli or aws web console? I was not able to find it. Thank you for help!

Jan

Comment: How did it go with the issue? The problem still persists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EC2 Auto Scaling Group's Instance refresh goes below Healthy threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450211/ec2-auto-scaling-groups-instance-refresh-goes-below-healthy-threshold)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [instance refresh](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-instance-refresh-for-ec2-auto-scaling/). For AWS CLI this is [start-instance-refresh](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/start-instance-refresh.html) and have to adjust `MinHealthyPercentage`.

For AWS console you have:

[image]

Comment: If you have only one instance in ASG it does not work, there is an outage even if you set 100% in the window. If you have 2 and more instances, it works just fine. But if you trigger it via terraform, it works fine even if you have only one instance.

Comment: @Trepliev If you set max capacity to 1, this could happen. Have you tried with max capacity of ASG of 2, when you have desired capacity of 1?

Comment: I have desired 1, minimum 1, maximum 2 instances